# Undefined variable: post in home.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, variables, undefined

This is my Admincontroller

```php
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\Models\Post;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    
    class AdminController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(){
            $data=DB::table('post')->get();
            return view('admin.home',['post'=>$data]);
        }
        public function add(){
            return view('admin.add');
        }
        public function addpost(Request $request){
            request()->validate([
                'title'=>'required|max:50',
                'post'=>'required|max:500'
            ]);
    
            DB::table('post')->insert([
                'title'=>request('title'),
                'post'=>request('post')
            ]);
    
            return view('admin.home');
        }
    
        public function edit(Post $post){
            return view('admin.edit',['post'=>$post]);
        }
        public function editpost(Request $request, Post $post){
            request()->validate([
                'title'=>'required|max:50',
                'post'=>'required|max:500'
            ]);
            DB::table('post')->update([
                'title'=>request('title'),
                'post'=>request('post')
            ]);
            return redirect('home');
        }
        public function deletepost(Post $post){
            $post->delete();
            return redirect('home');
        }
    }
```

This is my routes

```php
    <?php
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\LogoutController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController;
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Web Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
    |
    */
    
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
    Route::get('/home',[AdminController::class,'index']);
    Route::get('/add',[AdminController::class,'add'])->middleware('auth');
    Route::post('/addpost',[AdminController::class,'addpost']);
    Route::get('/edit/{post}',[AdminController::class,'edit']);
    Route::post('/editpost/{post}',[AdminController::class,'editpost']);
    Route::get('/delete/{post}',[AdminController::class,'deletepost']);
    Route::post('/logout',[LogoutController::class,'logout']);
    Route::get('/login',[LoginController::class,'login'])->name('login');
    Route::post('/logindetails',[LoginController::class,'logindetails']);
    Route::get('/register',[RegisterController::class,'register']);
    Route::post('/registerdetails',[RegisterController::class,'registerdetails']);
```

and this is home.blade.php

```html
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            @auth
                <a href="\home"><button>HOME</button></a>
                <a href="\add"><button>ADD</button><a>
                <form method="post" action="\logout" style="display:inline-block;">
                @csrf
                <button>LOGOUT</button>
                </form> <!--here-->
            @endauth
            @guest
                <a href="\login"><button>LOGIN</button></a>
                <a href="\register"><button>REGISTER</button></a>    
            @endguest
            
            
            @foreach($post as $data)
                <article> {{$data->title}}<br> {{$data->post}} 
                @auth <a href="\edit\{{$data->id}}">edit</a>| <a href="\delete\{{$data->id}}">delete</a>@endauth
                </article>
            @endforeach
        </body>
    </html>
```

The error says Undefined variable: post (View: C:\installationxampp\htdocs\samplelaravel1\resources\views\Admin\home.blade.php)

In home.blade.php the calling of the $post is invalid because its undefined while my edit
pages are successfully retrieving the information from my database while when I call $post
in home.blade.php it does not work. I'm in Laravel Framework 5.8.38

I've also done :

```php
    public function index(){
        $data=DB::table('post')->get();
        return view('admin.home',compact('post'));
    }
       
    public function index(){
        $data=DB::table('post')->get();
        return view('admin.home')with(['posts' => $data]);
    }
       
    public function index(){
        $data['post']=DB::table('post')->get();
        return view('admin.home',$data);
    }
```

but did not work

Comment: In your `index()`-controller, you're loading `admin.home` while passing `$post`, but in `addpost()`, you're calling the same view _without_ passing `$post` as a parameter. That should give you `Undefined variable` since that view expects and assumes there is a `$post` variable passed.

Comment: In your last examples, you don't pas `$post` anywhere. You should read about [compact()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) to understand how to use that function (you're using it wrong). You should also read up on [how to pass data to views in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#passing-data-to-views). If you want a variable to exist in the view, you need to pass them as an array with `['variableName' => 'variableValue']`. That will create a variable called `$variableName` in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass `$post` to view or redirection in your controller

Answer (score 1):

change your function index into :

```
public function index(){
    $post=DB::table('post')->get();
    return view('admin.home', compact('post'));
}
```

Comment: Their index-method should already work "as is" though (if you ignore the OP's posted attempts at the end of the question). However, they didn't pass any data at all to the same view in the `addpost()` method. Also, when posting an answer, make sure you explain what you've changed and why so the OP (and future visitors) can learn from it and not just copy/paste the code without knowing _why_ it solved which the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
{
    $post = Post::all();
    return view('admin.home', compact('post'));
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.